# Morph Camera from perspective to Panoramic

Tags: rendering, camera, keyframes, graph-editor, panoramic

Is it possible to ease the camera type from perspective to panoramic? or is there a work around to do this?

Is there a mathematical approach to this?

Comment: If you use Equirectangular panorama, you can earn similar results as the perspective camera if you use little values for Latitude and Longitude. For example Latitude +-14 and Longitude +-25 is pretty similar as the 35mm Focal lenght camera. You can animate these values if you pull above the mouse them and press the "I" key.

Comment: @FFeller cool, i will try this out

Comment: This is close but not quite what I want, Probable gonna do some effects post render to jimmy rig what I'm looking for, but maybe someone else will know of another way to cheat it.